# on server start, process hwrng in "D" state causing load_average = 1

Tags: debian, systemd, load-average

In a newly installed server (Debian 8), the average load never goes under 1 beside the fact there is almost nothing runnning, %CPU usage is always at 0%.

After some search I found the process `hwrng` (parent process = `kthreadd`) may be the cause, but I don't know how to prevent that.

Here the first lines of the `top` :

```
top - 11:26:02 up 16:51,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.02, 1.05
Tasks:  86 total,   1 running,  85 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.7 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1007204 total,   898320 used,   108884 free,    92112 buffers
KiB Swap:   524284 total,     2324 used,   521960 free.   296008 cached Mem
```

And the `ps aux|grep D` output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root       537  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Jul29   0:00 [hwrng]
```

ps axo stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm|grep 'hwrng\|kthreadd'

```
STAT  EUID  RUID TT       TPGID  SESS  PGRP  PPID   PID %CPU COMMAND
D        0     0 ?           -1     0     0     2   537  0.0 hwrng
S        0     0 ?           -1     0     0     0     2  0.0 kthreadd
```

On an other server installed at the same time (and same distrib), this process is not present and the load average is most of time 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware and virtual servers may get low on true randomness entropy. Debian explain this in their wiki article [BoottimeEntropyStarvation](https://wiki.debian.org/BoottimeEntropyStarvation) and there are a few suggestions how to fix this. If you end up with "haveged", you can review the tutorial [How to Setup Additional Entropy for Cloud Servers Using Haveged](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged) by Digital Ocean.

If "haveged" doesn't start on your Debian system due to AppArmor profile issues, review [Debian bug #911604](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911604) which suggests a quick fix.